# SQL violation of primary key constraint replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-replication

I'm trying to make a replication between an sql server 2008 to 2012
I have done that before between 2008 server and works perfectly

Now when I set the publication type to snapshot, and doing it as a push from the distributor to the subscriber I'm getting an error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tableF__4EBD61D204E4BC85'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table'. The duplicate key value is (0). (Source : MSSQLServer, Numéro d'erreur : 2627)
>   Obtenir de l'aide : http://help/2627

Even if I selected only one table to replicate I had always the same problem, the schema of the database is created but no data in the table
I tried to ressed the table and it doesn't work.
Please what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Can you script out the publication and article, and paste it here?  would like to see what options you have set.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand how to script out the publication?

Answer (score 0):

I'm always with this problem
I tried to write a script instead of using the wisard

```
    DECLARE @publication AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriber AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriptionDB AS sysname;
DECLARE @frequency_type as int;
DECLARE @subscriber_security_mode as int;
DECLARE @subscriber_login AS sysname;
DECLARE @subscriber_password AS sysname;

SET @publication = N'8-9' ;
SET @subscriber =N'APPLI-SERV-EXT';
SET @subscriptionDB = N'89' ; 
SET @subscriber_security_mode= 1; 
SET @subscriber_login=N'xxx'; 
SET @subscriber_password=N'xxxx'; 

--Add a push subscription to a transactional publication.
USE [DBName]

EXEC sp_addsubscription 
@publication = @publication, 
@subscriber = @subscriber, 
@destination_db = @subscriptionDB, 
@subscription_type = N'push';

EXEC sp_addpushsubscription_agent 
@publication = @publication, 
@subscriber = @subscriber, 
@subscriber_db = @subscriptionDB, 
@subscriber_security_mode=@subscriber_security_mode,
@subscriber_login=@subscriber_login,
@subscriber_password=@subscriber_password,
@frequency_type = @frequency_type,
@job_login = N'xxxx', 
@job_password = N'xxx';
GO
```

when I execute I got a warning  "Warning : the work of the distribution agent Was implicitly created and will run under the service account of the SQL Server Agent."

If I check the subscriber I found that the schema is replicated and instead to have a 418 row in the table I have 4012 and the table is empty except a not null attribute which is 0
here is the script of the table

```
    USE [test]
GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[clientEssai]    Script Date: 15/09/2015 15:13:44 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[clientEssai](
        [client_id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [client_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [contact_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [tel] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [gsm] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [email] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [adress] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [registration_date] [date] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

P.S: I selected only one article to replicate which is the table ClientEssai
Publisher and Distributor are the 2008 instance
subscriber 2012
I'm doing a push
and I'm using the same account for the agents
Is there a particular configuration to do?
Thank you